# How to scroll web page 20px-50px down when page loading?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Please check 54.164.28.219
When the site loading left menu doesn't show proper position.
But when I scroll couple of pixels down page is looking Good.
Any solution to fix or how to scroll couple of pixel down from top when initialize.

Answer (score 1):

For moving 0 pixel use window.scroll.to(horizontal pixel , vertical pixel)

as example this code will moce 1 pixel vertically:

```
<script>
window.onload=toBottom;

function toBottom()
{
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css code:

```
body {
  padding-bottom:50px//change this till it is perfect
}
```

This is because you have a sticky footer and it overlaps the content.

Comment: I think this is not main problem. I use custom header. Please check. Is there any solution to scroll 10-15 px from top when page loading?